# Seek Bar in Flash

Tags: actionscript-3

I have created a flash movie in AS3, I wanted to have a seek bar [or a Back and Forward button] to move my movie forward/backward.

Any ideas on how to get this done?

Help appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Have you even tried something?

Comment: I cannot get hold of anything as of now! Been only sometime, since I have started working on Flash! So things are pretty new.

Comment: Do you want a seek bar from Flash CS3 components or pure ActionScript 3 code ? What type of movie is it ? Flv ? Are you using the NetStream Class to load your movie ? Feed us :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fast. Since you cannot get a hold of anything :D :S

For Rewind

Make a Button say *RewindBtn*

Add an event listener say *RwdBtnRelease* when the Rewind Button is realeased

If you are using the NetStream class

then this all you add to the *RwdBtnRelease* function

```
ns.seek(0); // Assuming your NetStream instance is named ns
```

Then for play

Make a Button say *PlayBtn*

Add an event listener say *PlayBtnRelease* when the Play Button is realeased

If you are using the NetStream class

then this all you add to the *PlayBtnRelease* function

```
ns.pause(); // Assuming your NetStream instance is named ns
```

Done and done so when the play button is clicked when playing it is paused and vice versa. For the rewind it sets the video back to the beginning.

Comment: I dont want to go to only the Frame 0, but anywhere in the TimeLine, which is the concern. And moreover, many frames in swf have movie clips.

Comment: I am talking about a flv control (0 is **not** frame 0, it refers to the offset in the stream so ns.seek(10) means play at 10 seconds from the beginning of the **movie**) ... I am not sure what you are talking about. @sharvey asked if you have you tried something and I want to know the same. Nowhere in your question did you talk about frames. Please take the time to edit your question and explain what you are having problems with.